# Ubuntu 12.04 ethernet is not working ( Unclaimed Network)

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, kernel, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.5

I upgraded the kernel to `3.13.0-100-generic` to install docker engine.

After upgrading kernel, ethernet has stopped working and it is showing as unclaimed network.

```
 *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 64:5a:04:3d:8a:f6
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-100-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.3.214 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:f7e00000-f7e7ffff memory:f7e80000-f7e8ffff

*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 0c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

Please help to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

@Vivek: Did you also upgrade the kernel headers module at the time of installing the new kernel? If not, you may try by doing `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. Regards